# Are the conditional probabilities of MATLAB's mnrval correct?

Tags: matlab, statistics, regression, probability, logistic-regression

An MWE (stats toolbox required, tested on MATLAB R2014b):

```
x = (1:3)';
b = mnrfit(x,x,'model','hierarchical');
pihat = mnrval(b,x,'model','hierarchical','type','conditional')
```

Output:

```
pihat =
            1            1
   2.2204e-16            1
   2.2204e-16   2.2204e-16
```

(Ignore the issued warning, it's because of the trivial example, which is linearly separable (I'm predicting `x` using itself). It doesn't matter: I've tried this as well with a non-trivial (and not-so minimal) example without the warning and the results are similar.)

My problem is the result. I've specified I want the conditional probabilities. According to MATLAB's documentation on [`mnrval`](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/mnrval.html#input_argument_namevalue_type):

> Specify [`'conditional'`] to return predictions [...] in terms of the first `k – 1` conditional category probabilities [...], i.e., **the probability [...] for category `j`, given an outcome in category `j` or higher**.

In my example this means rows of `pihat` contain the probability of

1. `x=1` given `x>=1`
2. `x=2` given `x>=2`

(A third column for `x=3` is not necessary, because if the first two probabilities are known, the third is too. It follows logically from `P(x=1) + P(x=2) + P(x=3) = 1`.)

Am I interpreting this correctly? Thus, if `x=1` is predicted, then the first column value should be large (close to one), because `P(x=1)` given `x>=1` is large. The second column should be close to zero, because `P(x=2)` given `x>=2` can't be large if `x=1`.

However, as you can see in the first row, the second column value is large as well as the first! I believe this is incorrect according to what the documentation specifies, am I right? The current (incorrect?) result implies the predicted probabilities in the rows are not of `x=j` given `x>=j`, but what are they then? Or how should I be interpreting them?

They are not equal to the cumulative probabilities, i.e. the probability of `x<=j`, which increases with `j`. I've checked this by calculating `pihat2 = mnrval(b,x,'model','hierarchical','type','cumulative'); pihat2-pihat`.